# Access treemap in another class and loop through the items

Tags: java

Here's my first Java class, which includes the TreeMap that I want to loop through:

```
package myFunctions;

import java.util.TreeMap;

public class myUrls {

    public void  main() {
    
        TreeMap<String, String> getUrl = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        
        getUrl.put("app1", "URL 1");
        
        getUrl.put("app2", "URL 2");           
        
      }
    
    // Print keys and values
    for (String i : getUrl.keySet()) {
      System.out.println("app name: " + i + " url: " + getUrl.get(i));
     
    }
    
 }
}
```

Here's my second class, where I want to take the previously mentioned TreeMap and loop through it:

```
package myFunctions;

public anotherClass() {

    DA_devurl myUrls = new DA_devurl(); 
    
    //Loop through the array and perform seperate actions for each keyvalue pair

}
```

Comment: you are asking to access a variable defined in a function from another class, which is not possible. Either define the map as a instance variable of first class, or pass the map to second class method as an argument, or return the map from the first function

Comment: You can instantiate the treeMap as a class variable. Call the main method which will add values to treeMap. 
Then use a forEach on top of that.
Overall code: 
DA_devurl myUrls = new DA_devurl(); 
myUrls.main();
myUrls.getUrl.entrySet.forEach(e -> { write your code });

Answer (score 2):

In your first class, I recommend making your TreeMap a private instance variable with a getter method:

```
package functions;

import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MyUrls {
    private TreeMap<String, String> getUrl;

    public MyUrls() {
        getUrl = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void main() {
        getUrl.put("app1", "URL 1");
        getUrl.put("app2", "URL 2");           
    } 

    public TreeMap<String, String> getGetUrl() {
        return this.getUrl;
    }
}
```

Now, in your second class, all you need to do is call the getter method after creating an instance of your previous class, and then looping through its entries with the proper syntax:

```
package functions;

import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AnotherClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      MyUrls myUrl = new MyUrls(); 
    
      // populates the TreeMap
      myUrl.main(); 
      TreeMap<String, String> urls = myUrl.getGetUrls();
    
      // Loop through the array and perform seperate actions for each keyvalue pair
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : urls.entrySet()) {
         // do something with entry.getKey() and entry.getValue()
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: @matt whoops, was just going off of the posted code. fixed!